# Php base64 encode different results

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I have a php script that converts images to base64. Running locally all is fine and it decodes and displays but when I send it to mysql via curl post it is generating a different string. The first 1/4 of the strings match then it all changes. I have searched for hours and still none the wiser if anyone can help?

```
$newImg = "Path to image"; 
$imgBinary = fread(fopen($newImg, "r"), filesize($newImg)); 
$imgString = base64_encode($imgBinary); 
$string = "FName=SName= etc etc etc Photo=".$imgString; 
$url ="Url to web service"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
$phpArray = json_decode($output, true); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Show the code maybe? I'm 100% sure base64 isn't a problem but your script is.

Comment: Hi barell, Yes its here.

Comment: $newImg = "Path to image";
$imgBinary = fread(fopen($newImg, "r"), filesize($newImg));
$imgString = base64_encode($imgBinary);
$string = "FName=SName= etc etc etc Photo=".$imgString;
$url ="Url to web service";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
$phpArray = json_decode($output, true);
curl_close ($ch);

Comment: what debugging have you done yourself? e.g. checked the data at the receiving end **BEFORE** you get mysql involved?

Comment: I have debugged all steps and the web service is echoing a different string from post so its a problem with my script as far as I can see.

Comment: Ok so I have run it all locally and it works fine. Both in mysql and a a local web service to var_dump the post. When I send it to the remote web service and echo out the post it is showing a different string. There is no other code before I echo out the post field. It is a complete mystery!

Answer (score 0):

$string must be urlencoded with urlencode php function

Comment: Sorry I should have stated I did that too, urlencoding would not change the whole string and half the characters in it though.

Comment: I cant sorry. But it is happening somwhere between the script and the web service.